# SQL Server - Calculate AVG() using Joins

Tags: sql-server, join, average

I have a Cab transport application

Each driver has a Trip and for each trip, there can be multiple customers (Cab pooling) giving their feedback.

Now I want to get the drivers of those drivers who got more than 10 five star ratings(5*) and a minimum of 20% Five-star ratings out of their total Ratings received from their customers.

Let's say a driver got a total 40 feedbacks in the last 30 days out of which 16 are 5-star ratings, then this driver has met the criteria of minimum 10 5* star ratings and more than 20% 5* ratings. This driver id should be fetched.

```
SELECT TR.[DriverId]
    ,100.0 * AVG(CASE 
            WHEN FE.[Rating] = 5
                THEN 1.0
            ELSE 0
            END) AS Percentage
FROM tblFeedback FE
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTrip TR ON FE.TripId = TR.TripId
WHERE FE.DATE >= GETDATE() - 30
    AND FE.Rating = 5
GROUP BY DriverId
HAVING COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN FE.[Rating] = 5
                THEN DriverId
            END) >= 10
    AND 100 * AVG(CASE 
            WHEN FE.[Rating] = 5
                THEN 1.0
            ELSE 0
            END) > 20
```

The above query is showing the Percentage as 100.000 for all the Drivers whose Id's are fetched, even those drivers whose total percentage is 18% are also fetched and their percentage is shown as 100%.

This query has screwed my report completely

Comment: your case statement is at fault. If the rating is 5 then you're returning 1 (aka 100%), otherwise, all other ratings are 0. the average of all 1's is 1. 100.0 * 1 = 100* also your where clause is filtering out all non-5 values...

Comment: any help on what should be in the case statement, or any better approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You need to include all the ratings in order to calculate the percentage:

```
SELECT r.[DriverId], 100.0*r.five_stars/r.total_ratings AS Percentage
FROM (
  SELECT TR.[DriverId]
    SUM(CASE WHEN FE.Rating =5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS five_stars,
    SUM(*) AS total_ratings
  FROM tblFeedback FE
  INNER JOIN tblTrip TR ON FE.TripId = TR.TripId
  WHERE FE.DATE >= GETDATE() - 30
  GROUP BY TR.DriverId) r
WHERE r.five_stars>=10
AND 100.0*r.five_stars/r.total_ratings>20.0;
```

Comment: I am getting incorrect syntax error at   --- SUM(CASE WHEN FE.Rating =5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS five_stars, SUM(*) AS total_ratings --- near the comma after five_stars it is giving syntax error... also SUM(*) is also having error

Comment: TR.[DriverId] is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function -- also SUM(*) is giving an error

Comment: GROUP BY TR.[DriverId], not [DriverId]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your `WHERE` clause. This line in particular:

`AND FE.Rating = 5`

This is forcing the `tblFeedback` table to only return records that have a five-star rating, and therefore, only the five-star ratings are used in the calculation. Try taking that line out and see if the calculations are any closer to what you expect.